# Unified class of an object type "Group"?

Tags: pattern-matching, combinatorics, group-theory

Does Mathematica support an unified class for "group-type" objects? Or, less general, for groups with a fixed defined representation in Mathematica?

For example:

```
a = Cycles[{{1, 2}}]; b = Cycles[{{3, 4}}]; group = PermutationGroup[{a, b}];
MatchQ[group, _PermutationGroup]
```

Result: `True`

but

```
MatchQ[DihedralGroup[8], _PermutationGroup]
```

Result: `False`

even though `DihedralGroup[8]` support the group-based functions as a `CycleIndexPolynomial` , `GroupElements` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Based on spelunking symbols like `GroupGenerators` or `AlternatingGroup`, I do not believe there is a unified way to test if an expression represents a group.

---

There does seem to be an internal function, `` GroupTheory`PermutationGroups`Private`NamedGroupQ ``, which will give `True` for any named group (except `PermutationGroup`). I would *not* advise using it. It is part of the internal implementation, it is not clear what it's for exactly, and it comes with absolutely no guarantees.

---

If you are writing functions that should be able to operate on any group, probably the best approach is to just go ahead and use the group function, then [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) if they issued any error messages. These messages may be because something is not a group, or because Mathematica has no data on the given group.

If you are going to introduce your own group symbol, then you have two reasonable options:

- Either make it evaluate to a `PermutationGroup` immediately, or, if this is not desirable due to performance reasons,
- Create UpValue definitions for each relevant group functions. This is how e.g. `AlternatingGroup` is implemented.